# MVC 3 Data Annotation Attributes ignored intermittently

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

I've extended DataAnnotationExtensions project with support for Min/Max/RangeWords validations, both server- and client-side. Validations work beautifully, but I'm seeing the following problem:

Given a field in the model described as

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a short description")]
[MaxWords(40, ErrorMessage = "Description is too long - 40 words max")]
[DisplayName("Business description")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Data.MultilineText only has effect immediately after I recompile the project (and/or make some changes that require recompile). After that, **multi-line** class doesn't get added to the field in question. In other words: the first time I run the form, everything looks fine; on the second run, the attribute is apparently ignored, and I'm getting a single-line text box.

I should point out that in the project, error messages and descriptions are not in English, but in Hebrew (not sure if that has any effect). Additionally, validation works, both inside this project and in a separate test project.

What could be the culprit?  Is it something on my side, or a bug in DataType processing?

Thanks and regards,
Ilya.

Comment: Is using the @Html.TextAreaFor in your View an option for you to get the multiline textbox without using the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You should use text area in you view if you can.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
```

You could also write [EditorTemplate](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx) for this, implement the html that you want and use the `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)`

Hope this helps